# Mysql query to retrieve missing combination at a relationship table

Tags: mysql, database, combinations, relationship

I have four tables (A,B,C and D). Table "D" has the FK relationship from the other three tables. How would be a query to retrieve all Ids from Table "A" that has no complete combinations with B and C table records ids at table "D"? Example:

Table A

```
id  Value
1   Orange
2   Apple
3   Lemon
4   Strawberry
6   Grape
```

Table B

```
id  value
1   Juice
2   Ice cream
```

Table C

```
id  Value
1   $10
2   $20
```

Table D

```
id  IdA IdB IdC Value
1   2   2   1   Desc 1
2   2   1   1   Desc 2
3   2   2   2   Desc 3
4   2   1   2   Desc 3
5   1   1   1   Desc 4
6   3   2   1   Desc 5
```

How to select all ids from table A that does not have all possible combinations (relationships) at table D with both IdB and IdC? In the example above, only IdA = 2 has all combinations, so a query would return all ids from table A, except id = 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the missing combinations using this query:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from tablea a cross join
     tableb b cross join
     tablec c left outer join
     tabled d
     on d.ida = a.id and d.idb = b.id and d.idc = b.id
where d.ida is null;
```

If you just want the missing values from `tablea` that have no matches, then use `group by` and `having`:

```
select a.*
from tablea a cross join
     tableb b cross join
     tablec c left outer join
     tabled d
     on d.ida = a.id and d.idb = b.id and d.idc = b.id
where d.ida is null
group by a.id
having sum(d.ida is null) > 0;
```